# Unexpected button padding on ICS

Tags: android, nine-patch, statelistdrawable

I have a custom button with a state list drawable that has a tight layout with very little padding. This button looks great on MDPI and HDPI devices, but padding is all wrong on my Motorola Xoom (ICS, MDPI device). Modifying the 'padding' and 'margin' attributes does nothing.

Anyone have any suggestions on what may be causing the unnecessary padding? I'm fairly confident that both the state list drawable and the 9patch drawables are fine (they render perfectly on other MDPI devices).

Attached is an example of what the final product looks like - green border denotes its ideal appearance (and the way the button looks on other devices); magenta border denotes the appearance on the Xoom.[image]

Comment: Incidentally, using a focusable, clickable TextView instead of a Button renders the widget correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered some situation when developing a appwidget. I added a button and try to trim all paddings of it to make it small but failed, there are always a top padding and a bottom padding. I believe it's a constraint of Android system, so that all buttons in appwidget are large enough for end users to tap. However sometimes we insist small buttons due to boss... As the workaround Melllvar indicated, I used a focusable, clickable TextView instead of a Button, it works as expected.