# Unexpected top and bottom padding on a TextView?

Tags: android

I have a TextView. I want to set its background color. But the color fills more top space than it does bottom space.

```
<!-- red background. -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:text="10.0" />
```

This is how it renders (zoomed in to demonstrate, green lines added by me):

[image]

So the extra space up top makes it look like the text is not centered within its own container. Is this expected? I'd like the text to appear vertically centered within its own container (the red area).

This is on a galaxy nexus, stock version of jellybean.

Thanks

Comment: If in appwidget, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629249/unexpected-button-padding-on-ics/20135309#20135309

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following attribute:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Awesome, have always been looking for that!

Comment: this is the nth time i end up here and it's awesome every time